# Entity Framework Relationship Query Confusion

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am a EF newb and need some help with how to query an entity through a navigation property.

Using C# and LINQ Lambda Methods only I am using to get this code:

```
 List<PublisherImage> images = db.DataModel.PublisherImages.Include("Categories").Where(pi => pi.Enabled && pi.Rendered).OrderBy(pi => pi.ID).ToList();
```

I need to be able to filter this entity by a list of category IDs so I get publisher images by that category. Using the example above, how would I do what I am used to in SQL (an IN statement)?

Can someone show me an example using C# LINQ Lambda Methods and not LINQ Operators?

Thanks so much!

EDIT:

Here is a better example of what I am trying to do:

```
 string categoryIds = "1,2,3,4";
 var ids = Array.ConvertAll(categoryIds.Split(','), int.Parse);
 List<PublisherImage> images = db.DataModel.PublisherImages.Include("Categories").Where(pi => pi.Enabled && pi.Rendered && pi.Categories.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.ID)).Any()).OrderBy(pi => pi.ID).ToList();
```

Comment: This question seems unclear. Could you supply a little more information about your model, and the values you're trying to filter on? It sounds to me that you could do a `.Where(pi => ids.Contains(pi.ID))` but I don't know what your objects/relations look like.

Comment: I just added a better code example.

Comment: Ok, this code is more clear, but what is your problem? It seems like this would do what you want.

Comment: What error message are you getting

Comment: Man, I wrote that code without running it not thinking it was going to work. I will test before I post next time. The code I have does work. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

From your last code just try changing to pi.Categories.Any(c => ids.Contains(c.ID))

writing on my phone so sorry for not writing the whole query.

Answer (score 0):

The code under EDIT does work:

```
 string categoryIds = "1,2,3,4";
 var ids = Array.ConvertAll(categoryIds.Split(','), int.Parse);
 List<PublisherImage> images = db.DataModel.PublisherImages.Include("Categories").Where(pi => pi.Enabled && pi.Rendered && pi.Categories.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.ID)).Any()).OrderBy(pi => pi.ID).ToList();
```